# Does ultisnips support html?

Tags: linux, vim, html, vim-plugins

Ultisnips works fine with python and c, but when edit html files, it never insert the snippet at all. While youcomplete me suggest there is a snippet by the prompt.

Does ultisnips support other languages other than c and python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the problem was you can't type the whole tag to trigger ultisnip. E.g.:

`head<Trigger>` will output the snip but `<head><Trigger>` will not.

Answer (score 3):

Ultisnips supports custom snippets for all *filetypes*, but it doesn't ship with any default snippets. These are provided by [honza/vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets), which includes (among many) [HTML](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/snippets/html.snippets).

So yes, it does support them. Why that doesn't work for you would require more troubleshooting information. Especially, ensure that `:setlocal filetype?` returns `html`.

Comment: Yes, these all met. I install the snippets, so I can get c or python file working, filetype also returns html. I suspect if there are conflicts between the plugins. Nothing was printed in :messages, and I don't know where else can look for the information.

Comment: Try disabling other plugins. If you can still reproduce this, I'd recommend to ask for help on the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:map` command to make sure that the key that ultisnips uses for expanding snippets (`g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger`, `<tab>` by default) isn't re-mapped by another plugin that is used for HTML files.